# Custom thread local random number generator

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, prng

Up to now I was always just creating my own threads the old fashion way (prior to 1.5 java concurrent).
But I would like to check out the Executors and stuff. I basically know how to use them, but in my case  I need that each thread has it's own random number generator. I know that Java 1.7 has that ThreadLocalRandom which is exactly what I would like to achieve but with my own PRNG (be it QMC or anything else).

So again:

I want to create executor which is a pool of 8 threads and give it a bunch of tasks that use my own random generator which is local for each Thread (each thread has it's own instance created with different seed). What is the best way to do it? Preferably the cleanest and with the best performance.
ThreadLocal maybe? I haven't ever had to use that, but who knows...

Thanks,
Michal.

Comment: To make it clear, I'm not looking for code or anything. I know how I could do it, I'm asking what's the best way.

Comment: You can have the `Executor` use your own `Thread` implementations by providing a `ThreadFactory` to the [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,%20java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory%29). However, your tasks would then have to cast their current thread's class and that is not really a clean approach.

Comment: But yes, I think `ThreadLocal` is the right way to go here.

Comment: Just curious... this is useful when using a fixed `seed` per thread, isn't it (you won't be using `System.currentTimeMillis` or something like that).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. However I think that both ThreadLocal and custom ThreadFactory are not the cleanest solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you need each thread to have its own RNG, using ThreadLocal is probably the easiest way.

In my opinion this is not a very clean solution however, as it couples the threads belonging to the executor to the specific tasks. I think in general it would make more sense to assign the RNGs to the task objects instead.

With the additional information given, I think the best would be to create a class, ie MyTask, implementing Runnable that represents the task of reading image areas from the list, processing them, and then continuing to the next. The task would finish when there are no more areas to process, or when an error is encountered. MyTask would have its own private RNG to use for the image generation.

```
MyTask  implements Runnable {
    private final Random random;
    // Queue is shared
    private final Queue<ImageArea> areasToProcess;

    public MyTaks(Random random, Queue<ImageArea areasToProcess) {
        this.random = random;
        this.areasToProcess = areasToProcess;
    }

    public void run() {
        ImageArea areaToProcess;
        while((areaToProcess = areasToProcess.poll()) != null) {
            process(areaToProcess);
        }
    }
}
```

With a runnable class like this you could easily use either threads directly or an ExecutorService. Note that the class assumes that the queue containing the image areas to process is filled before processing starts.

Comment: I'm rendering an image, each task renders let's say a horizontal line or a small portion of the image (like 32x32px). Not going into details rendering takes a bunch of random numbers. Up until now I was just creating 8 different threads each had it's own prng, only a pool of image portions were shared so the thread/task knew which part to render (and then jumped to next one). Probably executors don't fit here that well.